Struggling to link tables in PowerApps
I'm in the process of building a PowerApp as a proof of concept.  I've got a browse screen which displays all of my buildings - it's got the address, building type and building reference so there's nothing complicated there.
When I go into the detail, I've got extra details about the building - things like it's size, how many rooms, etc.  What I've also done is add a Gallery to display information about the tenancies which is coming from a table called Tenancy.
Filter(tblTenancy,PropertyId = BrowseGallery1.Selected.'Unit ID'

I've then created a new screen because I want to see the details of the tenancy - i.e. the status, the start date, the end date but I also want to see the Client Name.  I've been able to bring back the Client ID because that's in the tblTenancy table but I can't work out how I can get the Client Name.
I have another list called Client and it has 5 fields - Title (which is actually the Client Reference), Name, DOB, Telephone and Gender.  As I say, this is a proof of concept.
I've tried to set the input with:
LookUp(Client, 'Title' = Gallery1.Selected.'Title').'Name'

but when I preview it just displays that rather than the name of the person.  The tenancy details are there - I can see an ID, the start date, end date, status and Client ID but I can't bring back the name.
I think if I can do that then I'll pretty much have the app as I want it and add in extra fields but I think I'm not calling on the data in the Client list and/or I'm not joining it with the tenancy table.
Any steer would be greatly appreciated.

Are Clients, Tenancy and Property Dataverse tables? IN new screen where you want to see the details of tenancy what control you are using? Edit Form ,Display Form or Gallery ?I think you need to rethink your Tables and their relationship. They way you are trying to fetch records from two different tables in single gallery or form is not possible.

Review Real Estate Solution Example here, and then check the schema of table Real Estate Property in your developer environment, see how this table and Contact tables are used for the application. Your Property table must have fields like Real Estate Property and Client table must be same as Contact table (definitely add/delete fields in your table as per your requirement). If you want to keep the Tenancy table separate for keeping history of old and new tenancy records then you have to add separate screen in your application.
Also review Property Management Sample app for what I explain above. It will give you good idea.This App is using three collections for Property,Contact and Tenant, see how these collections is used in this application.If your tables are Dataverse tables then you can see table schema of Real Estate Property and Contact tables.



Thanks, the Real Estate Solution looks to be one table so I don't think that can help unfortunately.  The Property Management sample app looks like that would be more helpful but when I create that, I can't see an option for 'Data'... even the Add Data button doesn't work, so I'm not sure how I can see/use the structure and include additional fields.

Did you check the Real Estate Table? It is using client lookup for Contact table, so it's not single table solution. Property Management is using collections, If I am not wrong there are three different collections in used , check again.

It's probably me being confused but the link that you shared - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/build-canvas-app-real-estate-excel/exercise - contains an Excel file with this fields in a single worksheet -Address, ID, Price, Size, Owner, OwnerEmail, Image.

Sorry , I think I have confused you. Anyway I have edit my answer with screenshots for Property Management table. Just ignore the other example.

Thanks, really appreciate your help with this. I can see some things that may help, although the collections are new to me so I'll probably have to read up more.
